# How do I compare an input double value in an array to be null/String value("")?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a project and my Java program in Swing uses a double array to accept values from the user and print the total of the items, kind of like an order form. 
Say the user enters no value in the text box, this shows an error and prevents further calculations.
My question is ,**what should I code in order for the computer to understand that there is nothing entered in the text box , so just take the value as 0.** I want to either do this by comparing/converting the double array value to a string and then continuing with calculations .

Here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    double price[]=new double[]{0.25,8.55,0.50,0.25};
    double amount[]=new double[4];
    double quantity[]=new double[4];
    quantity[0]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    quantity[1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    quantity[2]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
    quantity[3]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)  // I want to use a for-loop or if-statement to 
                        check if there is a value entered or not
    {
        if()
        {
            quantity[i] //no clue what to do here.
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        {
            amount[i]=quantity[i]*price[i];
        }

    }
    jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf(amount[0]));
    jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(amount[1]));
    jTextField7.setText(String.valueOf(amount[2]));
    jTextField8.setText(String.valueOf(amount[3]));
```

Comment: And the question is...?  If the user enters no value, you typically do not calculate anything... which is just what you said, so I'm confused as to what the actual question is.

Comment: avoid use of `jTextField1,2.....`, Use appropriate name according to the attribute name, so that can make your code more readable

Comment: Use the JTextField.getText() option to compare it against values.

Comment: My question is ,what to code in order for the computer to understand that there is nothing entered in the text box , so just take the value as 0. I want to either do this by comparing the double array value to a string or converting the String to a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would want to check if the text fields are empty or a String value before parsing them. And you will likely need to do it for all of the fields.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // check the values of the text fields including an or condition for regular expressions
    if (jTextField1.isEmpty() || jTextField1.getText().matches("\\d+.?\\d*") {
        // you can use something like a modal to alert
        JOptionPane.showMessage(null,"Must enter a decimal value");
    } else {
        // do something with jTextField1
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, this kind of check can clutter the code with multiple fields to check so you may want to put it in it's own method and call that method passing each text field to be checked

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`if (!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty())`

Comment: This is a great suggestion/answer and will certainly help address part of the question. It is more helpful though to provide some explanation as to why this piece of code should work - also if you look at the code snippet - you can see that there are places where he parses values from fields as Doubles, this will break in case of empty fields - so you also would want to "warn" him about this and advise how best to refactor the code.